# Service Fabric .net core app not .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-stateless

We are in the process of building an service fabric application and have run into a bit of a issue, whenever you user Visual studio to create a new service fabric app and you specify to use a .Net core app, the app/api that is create is a .Net framework app and not .Net core.

```
<TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
```

Instead of:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

Does anyone know the reason for this, or is this intended behavior?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the preview tools to build and run .NET core apps.

> A preview of Visual Studio 2017 Service Fabric Tools 2.0 is now
>   available for download, packed with new .NET Core and Container
>   tooling for Service Fabric application development. To start using the
>   2.0 preview tools, you'll need to install:
>
> - Visual Studio 2017 Preview (version 15.4.0 preview 4.0 or later)
> - Service Fabric Tools 2.0 Preview

More info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/10/12/visual-studio-2017-service-fabric-tools-2-0-preview/).