# Service Fabric Creating CORE Web Api

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

When I creating Stateless service using VS template (even though I selected "Stateless ASP.NET Core"), the project gets created in .net 4.6.1

How come?

[image]

Comment: This may be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372498/service-fabric-net-core-app-not-net-core

Comment: Yes - the targetframework is .NET Framework. In the latest VS 2017, there are templates which target .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest service fabric tools (Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK version 3.0), there are new project templates for creating service fabric services.

see [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2018/01/26/service-fabric-6-1-release/) for more info.